# Python Relative Imports: Attempted relative import in a non-package

Tags: python, import, package

So I have a very simple package with the following structure:

```
package/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   subpackage/
       __init__.py
       b.py

a.py:
    print __name__
    from .subpackage.b import *

b.py

    print __name__
```

1) Why if I run `python -m a` from when inside package it returns: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. But If I leave the package directory and I run `python -m package.a` it works and prints:

```
__main__
package.subpackage.b
```

And also, why does it say `__main__` as `__name__` for a.py if I am running it as a module with`-m` option?

2) Why if then I write a `c.py` module that I put outside package that just imports `from package import a` I get:

```
package.a
package.subpackage.b
```

So I understand that now `__name__` from a is not `__main__` but why is that the case when I run it with as a module with `python -m` option. And why if I place that same `main.py` inside package, then the attempted relative import error appears again?

Comment: it varies between python versions, do you mind sharing what's yours?

Comment: Note the documentation description for `-m` is: "Searches `sys.path` for the named module and runs the corresponding `.py` file as a script." That's why `__name__` is `__main__`: you're running that `.py` file as a script. As @abccd says, the relative import details vary somewhat between versions; see [this q-and-a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/1256452) for instance.

Comment: @abccd I am using python 2.7.12